# How can I make VSCode suggest values from a dynamically generated enum?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, enums

I am saving roles, permissions of user on database.

Admins can add/delete/update roles, permissions from admin dashboard.

Inside app, I want to allow access to resources based on permissions of user.

To avoid typos and get autocomplete, instead of checking permission like:

```
user.has_permission('create_user')
```

I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE_USER = 'create_user'
user.has_permission(CREATE_USER)
```

So, to write all permissions, I am using `Enum` like below:

```py
RESOURCES = [
    "USER",
    "ROLE",
    "BLOG"
    ...
    ...
]
VERBS = ["LIST", "UPDATE", "DELETE", ......]

PERMISSION_LIST = []
for r in RESOURCES:
    for v in VERBS:
        PERMISSION_LIST.append((f"{v}_{r}", f"{v}_{r}"))

Permission = Enum("Permission", PERMISSION_LIST)
```

Now I can use,

```
user.has_permission(Permission.LIST_USER)
```

It works, but typing `Permission.` in vscode does not suggest any permission.

I can write every combination of permission instead of looping through resources and verbs. But I am avoiding it as that will be a long list.

I was looking at `metaclass` and feels that it can provide what I want, but I couldn't figure it out.

Is there a nifty trick in python's sleeve to store dynamic constants and provide completion suggestions in vscode.

Following code looks little manageable.

```py
class PERMISSION_BASE:
    CREATE = 1
    READ = 2
    UPDATE = 4
    DELETE = 8

class Permission:
    class User(PERMISSION_BASE):
        pass

    class ROLE(PERMISSION_BASE):
        pass
```

Now, I get autocompletion for `Permission.User.CREATE`. But it's kind of hacky and I will still have to type every RESOURCE (if not verbs).

Comment: This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.   In addition, we ask you limit each question to a single topic not multiple topics.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question. It's clear and specific problem is shown

Comment: @kosciej16 it is true that we ask for one question per post; additionally if something is "a good idea" is largely opinion-based, and opinion-based questions are off-topic.

Comment: @itprorh66, removed 2nd question.

Comment: VSCode - like any other IDE - is a separate program, not part of Python. Python isn't designed ahead of time to support all these editors; *they* support *Python* - because fundamentally there's an actual language to support, not just `python.exe`. So you don't want a "nifty trick" from the language; you want one from the IDE. The problem is that the IDE isn't providing completion suggestions, because it doesn't know what constants *will be* in the `Permission` enum, because the code to create it *hasn't run yet*. In general you should expect the IDE to do *static* analysis.

Comment: Before you run this code, the python can not know the value of `PERMISSION_LIST ` so It's impossible.